Is there a VS Code keyboard shortcut to rerun a code block?
In R Studio I can run a code block like this by highlighting and pressing Ctrl+Enter or going anywhere in the code block and pressing Alt+Enter:
data.frame(
  b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
  levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
  x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), 
  y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
  z = c(1, 1, 1, 2)
)

I can then go and make changes in R Studio's code editor and immediately press Ctrl+Alt+P to rerun the same code block, with my new changes implemented:
data.frame(
  b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
  levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
  # x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), 
  # y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
  z = c(1, 1, 1, 2)
)

So after pressing Ctrl+Alt+P in the R Studio editor that last code block would be rerun with the x and y columns commented out. This is very handy in my workflow.
Is there a way to "rerun last code block" in VS Code (with a keyboard shortcut)? I know I could press Ctrl+Enter (after re-highlighting) or go anywhere in the code block and press Alt+Enter, but there are circumstances where this doesn't quite work.
I really would like this R Studio "rerun last code block" functionality in VS Code. Is it possible? I checked and it doesn't seem to be an option in the REditorSupport VS Code extension.
